# User input file as parameter in URL to display data in file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an ASP.NET Web Service where I indicated the filepath of a .txt file which has some data in it in my controller class and when I run the application, the data that is in the .txt file is shown on the web browser in JSON format.

Here are the codes for that:

**FileReaderController**

```
public IHttpActionResult GET()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\attsuap1\Desktop\MillionCharsUpdate.txt";

        // Open the file and read
        string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        //Remove escape sequences
        content = content.Replace("\t\r\n", "");

        return Ok(new { Data = content });
    }
```

How do I edit this codes to make it such that user is able to input the .txt file as parameter in the URL instead of hardcoding it as a filepath?

I have edited **WebApiConfig.cs**

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ReadJsonChars",
            routeTemplate: "api/readjsonchars/{fileName}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", controller = "Reader" }
        );
```

I tried to do something like this to try to include a parameter:

**ReaderController**

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(String fileName)
    {
        string var = fileName;

        string data = ("C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\" + var);

        string content = File.ReadAllText(data);

        return Ok(new { Data = content });
    }
```

However it did not work. Someone please guide me on what I should do so I can achieve what I want. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you getting any error? What's in debug?

Comment: I do not get any error however when i run the application and put in .txt file in parameter, i get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` error. The .txt is under desktop

Comment: What does your HTTP request URL look like? That sounds like a 404 from the web server, not from your route, so you're probably not hitting your route.

Comment: `http://localhost:53456/api/readjsonchars/JsonChars.txt` this is the URL

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because your path contains dot '.' (JsonChars.txt).
You can fix it by modifying your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. I have modified the web.config however i do not get the results the page just keeps loading without showing any error page/data

Comment: @SushaNaidu ,
Have you tried to debug your app? Can it get the directory?
If not, try to use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()` to get your directory. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think it cant get the directory. I will try that method. So far what i have done, is it correct?

Comment: I got a question. What should i put in the bracket next to MapPath ? I do not want to hardcode the .txt file i want the user to input it in the URL as a parameter

Comment: Simple string concatenation of file directory and file name will do.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve what i wanted. Here are my codes:

**ReaderController.cs**

```
public class ReaderController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(String FileName)
    {
        string fileName = FileName;

        string path = "C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\" + fileName;

        string result = File.ReadAllText(path);

        result = result.Replace("\r\n", "");
        result = result.Replace("\t", " ");

        var resultDTO = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
        return Ok(resultDTO);
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ReadJsonChars",
        routeTemplate: "api/readjsonchars/{fileName}",
        defaults: new { action = "Get", controller = "Reader" }
    );
```

And also modified **Web.config**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

By doing this, when i run the application and input a .txt file in the parameter, the data that is in the .txt file is displayed on the web page.

Note: I had to deserialize as the data in the .txt file are in JSON format and i had cleared XML formatting therefore the result got double serialized.